# ARM64 Assembly Programming CMP instruction not working as expected

Tags: macos, assembly, apple-m1, arm64

I can't make cmp to work on arm64 assembly on Mac M1. I've tried everything but nothing seems to work.
For example in the code below cmp should evaluate to false and not printing, but instead it's printing Hello World. Why?

```
.global _start
.align 2



_start: 

    mov x3, #1
    cmp x3, #2
    b.eq _print_me
    

_print_me:  
    adr x1, _helloworld 
    mov x2, #15
    mov x16, #4
    svc 0
    b _terminate

_helloworld: .ascii "Hello World\n"

_terminate:
    mov x0, #0
    mov x16, #1
    svc 0
```

I've tried to change registers...same think. I am out of solutions.
I am new to assembly.
Thank you

EDIT 2: Why with two labels is printing both instead of one?

```
.global _start
.align 2



_start: 

    mov x3, #1

    cmp x3, #1
    b.eq _print_me



    b _terminate
    

_print_me:  

    adr x1, _helloworld 
    mov x2, #30
    mov x16, #4
    svc 0
    b _terminate
    

_print_me2: 
    adr x1, _helloworld2
    mov x2, #30
    mov x16, #4
    svc 0

    b _terminate

_terminate:
    mov x0, #0
    mov x16, #1
    svc #0x80

_helloworld: .ascii "Hello World\n"
_helloworld2: .ascii "Hello World2\n"
```

Comment: Why do you expect `#1` to be equal to `#2`? Shouldn't you branch to `_terminate` or fall through to the print routine?

Comment: It does "evaluate to false" and instead of taking the branch it falls through to the next instruction... and prints.

Comment: Recall that labels just mark a spot in your code.  The CPU does not know that labels exist and execution happily proceeds past labels.  As with every conditional branch, your `b.eq` instruction proceeds to the next instruction if the condition is false.  But as the next instruction is the one labelled with `_print_me`, it effectively always goes there.  Rearrange your code such that the code following the `_terminate` label comes after that branch.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I did not knew that execution goes pass if terminate not set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example has already been answered by @fuz in the comments: when the CPU *doesn't* take the branch, it continues executing at the next instruction. So that branch is essentially useless.

The issue with the second example becomes clear if you look at it in a disassembler. Specifically the target string. I'm using radare2 here:

```
[0x100003f48]> x 30 @sym._helloworld
- offset -   8C8D 8E8F 9091 9293 9495 9697 9899 9A9B  CDEF0123456789AB
0x100003f8c  4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 640a 4865 6c6c  Hello World.Hell
0x100003f9c  6f20 576f 726c 6432 0a00 0000 0100       o World2......
```

Both of your strings are laid out after each other in memory, and your specified length of 30 bytes spans across both of them, and then some bytes. The correct length would be 12 for the first string and 13 for the second.

It might be worth mentioning here that when dealing with C APIs, you should also be using `.asciz` instead of `.ascii` to get your strings zero-terminated, but this would make no difference here, since you're doing raw writes to a file descriptor.